# Can’t run Craft CMS on my local machine, keep getting message "The Mcrypt extension is required"

Tags: mcrypt

I try to run Craft on my local Windows server and I keep getting message:

> Can’t run Craft CMS :(
>   Your server doesn’t meet the following requirements to run Craft CMS:
>   The Mcrypt extension is required.
>   Please talk to your host/IT department about upgrading your server.

I tried installing Mcrypt, but I am having no luck... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

As of [Craft 2.7.0](https://craftcms.com/changelog#2-7-0), Craft 2 can run on PHP 7.2.

---

You're probably trying to install Craft 2 using PHP 7.2 (which doesn't have mycrypt installed by default), which isn't supported (see here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/requirements.html).

Your options are to:

1. Use Craft 3, which supports PHP 7.2 and doesn't use mcrypt.
2. Install mcrypt on PHP 7.2, but you'll probably run into other issues as well.
3. Stay on Craft 2 and drop down to PHP 7.1.